# Script to generate code based on pattern

Tags: regex, bash, vbscript, awk, language-agnostic

I am trying to generate code to re-initialize an object declared in a file xyz. For each variable declared as follows(x's denote any character, could be repeated any number of times):-

```
Private lst_xxxxxxxxx As xxxxxxxxxxx
```

or

```
Private _lst_xxxxxx As xxxxxxxxxxx
```

I want to generate something like:-

```
lstxxxxxxxx.Clear()
```

for each such occurrence, followed by a newline.

I tried using something like [^*[_ ]lst*] to match the lines in awk but it ended up capturing unwanted expressions
I can use any of the scripting tools from among the tags for this task, just need to get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question's tag is awk, looks you prefer awk.

```
awk '/Private.*As/{gsub(/_/,X,$2);print $2 ".Clear()"}' file

lsthey.Clear()
lsthelloooo.Clear()
```

If you need the output show as @fedorqui

```
awk '/Private.*As/{gsub(/_?lst_/,X,$2);print $2 ".Clear()"}' file

hey.Clear()
helloooo.Clear()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following `sed`:

```
sed -nr 's/Private _?(lst)_(\w*) As \w*/\1\2.Clear()/p' file
```

`-n` blocks the printing and `-r` allows to catch groups with just `()` and then print back with `\1`, `\2`...

#### Example

```
$ cat a
how are
Private lst_hey As you
Private _lst_helloooo As blabla
Private _lst_hello
you
i am ok

$ sed -nr 's/Private _?(lst)_(\w*) As \w*/\1\2.Clear()/p' a
lsthey.Clear()
lsthelloooo.Clear()
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it out anon

Comment: can be shorter. `sed -nr 's/^Private _?lst_(\w*) As \w*/\1.Clear()/p' file`

Comment: You are absolutely right, @BMW, there was no need to filter by `Private` lines. Updated. Thanks!

Comment: This has some problems. The _ is lost in the output. Also, I need the lst part to be retained. For example if it is _lst_xxx in the input , i want _lst_xxx.clear() in the output, not lst_

Comment: @BugKiller update your question, because this is not what you mention there. You indicate you want `lstxxx.Clear()`, without `_`.